# How can I save model and related models at the same time in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

My current version below, its work but in my code; first I save the model and after the related model.

```
    // Model        
    $pdf= new Canvas;
    $pdf->numero = $data['number'];
    $pdf->project = $data['title'];
    $pdf->date = $data['date'];
    $pdf->user_id = auth()->id();
    $pdf->type = 'type1';
        
    // Related model  
    $version = new Version;
    $version->json = 'teste2.json';
    $version->version = 1;
    $version->updated_by = auth()->id();
    
    //persist
    $canvas->save();
    $canvas->versions()->save($version);
```

What I need is:
how to save both model at the same time?

1. Create model
2. Create related model
3. Persist both model (related model get automatically the model_id)
4. if any problem happened, both model will not crated.

thanks so much

Comment: This might be what you're after: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions

Comment: You can use "observer" or "event/listener". Traits can also be useful. These are very big topics to explain here. So please do your own research.

Comment: @Rwd its interstine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can user this

```
$pdf = Canvas::create([
    'numero'  => $data['number'],
    'project' => $data['title'],
    'date'    => $data['date'],
   ...
]);

$pdf->versions()->create([
     'json'    => 'teste2.json',
     'version' => 1,
     ....

 ]);
```

Comment: We have the same problem here, Canvas model will be created befor Version model.